# distr package: two random variable multiplication operation error

Tags: r, statistics, distribution

I've been working on a large financial model and I'm trying to model uncertainties in the data. To do this, I've been modelling my variables as normal distributions (I know, I should probably use Weibull's or something, but this is just the easiest at the moment given my time contraints.

I've found the `distr` package, and it's wonderful implementation of math for statistical objects, but I can't figure out how to get the multiplication to work, given that I'm working with financial objects that are in the millions of $'s. I think I'm overloading some of the functions in the package, as they're intended to work on data like `X ~ [0,1]` not `X_mean = 70000, X_sd = 250`, which represent financial uncertainties.

Here's the code:

````
```{r one more thing}
library(distr)
library(tidyverse)

distroptions("DefaultNrFFTGridPointsExponent" = 50)
distroptions("DefaultNrGridPoints" = 2^50)

Containers <- Norm(mean=71000, sd=250)     
# Containers is how many containers we own in the wild
Container_Unit_Cap_Cost <- Norm(mean=85,sd=2) 
# Container_Unit_Cap_Cost is the unit cost to acquire new containers
Container_Total_Cap_Cost <- Containers * Container_Unit_Cap_Cost            
# Container_Total_Cap_Cost is product distribution of the two previous uncertain variables

xlim_min <- Container_Total_Cap_Cost@gaps[1,2]
xlim_max <- Container_Total_Cap_Cost@gaps[2,2]

ggplot(tibble(x = c(xlim_min, xlim_max)), aes(x)) +
  stat_function(fun = conv@d, n = 101) +   
  scale_y_continuous() + 
  theme_dark()

```
````

This has resulted in the error

```
Grid for approxfun too wide, increase DefaultNrFFTGridPointsExponentError in seq.default(from = lower, to = upper, by = h) : 'by' argument is much too small
```

with the following traceback from RStudio

```
14. stop("'by' argument is much too small")
13. seq.default(from = lower, to = upper, by = h)
12. seq(from = lower, to = upper, by = h)
11. .discretizeP(e1, lower, upper, h)
10. e10 + e20
9. e10 + e20
8. .class1(object)
7. as(e10 + e20, "UnivarLebDecDistribution")
6. log(e1DC$pos$D) + log(e2DC$pos$D)
5. log(e1DC$pos$D) + log(e2DC$pos$D)
4. .class1(object)
3. as(exp(log(e1DC$pos$D) + log(e2DC$pos$D)), "UnivarLebDecDistribution")
2. Containers * Container_Unit_Cap_Cost
1. Containers * Container_Unit_Cap_Cost
```

I've mucked around in the options for `distr` but can't seem to find a way to have it iterate with a larger interval for h. I've increased the `DefaultNrFFTGridPointsExponentError`

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found that by scrubbing my two option changes from the routine, and setting them back to default values, this ran without an issue. I don't know why the original error that prompted me to change them occurred, but this issue is now solved.